# Trouble parsing all directories in simple csh program

Tags: csh

I know that csh is bad, but it's required for this assignment. Anyway, I'm trying to write a program to grade a sample set of student assignments in a directory called dropbox:

```
#!/bin/csh
#
foreach directory (`ls dropbox`)
  if( ! -e dropbox/$directory/calculator ) then
   mkdir dropbox/$directory/calculator
   touch dropbox/$directory/calculator/comments
   echo "Directory did not exist and was created automatically" > dropbox/$directory/calculator/comments
  else
   touch dropbox/$directory/calculator/comments
   if( ! -e dropbox/$directory/calculator/calc.csh ) then
    echo "No submission from $directory at `date`" > dropbox/$directory/calculator/comments
   else if( ! -x dropbox/$directory/calculator/calc.csh ) then
    echo "Script not executable: -5 points" > dropbox/$directory/calculator/comments
   else
    touch dropbox/$directory/calculator/results
    echo "Results for $directory calculator script:" > 
    dropbox/$directory/calculator/calc.csh /afs/nd.edu/coursesp.14/cse/cse20189.01/files/hw5/calc > dropbox/$directory/calculator/results
    echo "Testing complete for $directory" > dropbox/$directory/calculator/results
   endif
  endif
end
```

The results for `ls dropbox` (All directories):

```
betty  charles  frank   izzy    lisa   ophelia  rosie  uhura   xena
bill   don      george  jackie  mark   paul     sandy  victor  yarek
bob    erin     hiram   kathy   nancy  quentin  tom    wally   zela
```

When I run the script, it returns a message saying that directory is undeclared. Any advice?

Comment: add a `cd /base/dir` before you start the `for` loop. If that fixes it, then you can decide if you want the `cd` inside the script, or if it makes sense to do it outside of the script. Good luck.

Comment: As you say, this is homework. We're willing to help but you need to trim your program down to something that works in someone else's environment. At the moment you're asking us to do your work for you.